# Xcode 7 How to get Text Field inputs?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

So I have been working with some swift code in xcode 7, and I am trying to make a basic login and registration page. I am trying to get the text inputs from the text fields, (Username, Password, etc), but I get an error (Value of type 'NSTextField' has no member 'text'. I have a note to mark where the error is in the code:

```
//  RegisterViewController.swift
//  SafeUtils
//
//  Created by DJtech on 7/26/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 DJtech. All rights reserved.
//

import Cocoa

class RegisterViewController: ViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var UserNameTextF: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var UserPasswordTextF: NSSecureTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var UserVerifyPassTextF: NSSecureTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }

    // When Register Button Tapped
    @IBAction func RegisterBTNTPD(sender: AnyObject) {
        //These are the parts of code that have the error. Error: Value of type 'NSTextField' has no member 'text'
        let Username = UserNameTextF.text
        let Password = UserPasswordTextF.text
        let veriPass = UserVerifyPassTextF.text


        // Are there empty fields?


        // Store User Data

        // Confirm Registration Message

    }


}
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: NSTextField you need to use `stringValue`

Comment: Sounds interesting, but could you be a bit more specific? How would I incorporate that into my code?

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can't use `text` to get the value of the `NSTextField`. Just check the [`NSControl`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSControl/stringValue) documentation, which the NSTextField inherits from. Because of that you can use `stringValue`:

```
let Username = UserNameTextF.stringValue
let Password = UserPasswordTextF.stringValue
let veriPass = UserVerifyPassTextF.stringValue
```

Also you don't have to use `;` at the end of each line in swift.

Answer (score -1):

here is this code that i have tried in play ground,, let me know how it goes

```
 var appUsers: [[String:String]] = [
[
    "userName": "Charly",
    "userPass": "123"
],
[
    "userName": "Betty",
    "userPass": "345"
],
[
    "userName": "Lenny",
    "userPass": "567"
],
[
    "userName": "Karl",
    "userPass": "789"
],
[
    "userName": "Homer",
    "userPass": "012"
]
]

    var loginName = "Betty"
    var loginPass = "345"

    var logginResult = ""

    for loggingUser in appUsers {

   if loginName == loggingUser["userName"] {

    if loginPass == loggingUser["userPass"] {

        let result = "ok"

        logginResult = result

    }
  }
}

if logginResult == "ok" {

  print("You are logged")

   // Do your logging stuff here

} else {

   print("Logging error")

   //Dou your return stuff here

}
```

Comment: I could see that working, but it wouldn't be secure because you can just view the passwords within whatever file this is.

Comment: i really don't see how ,,, because the upper part its a dictionary with your users and passwords,, and the code below ,, the loop, is for looping in your dictionary ,, and no one its looking at it ,, the var loginName and var loginName will be your textfield inputs and the result let you see if the name and password match and lets you proceed,, i don't se how it is insecure ,,no one its looking at your users,,,,

Comment: That answer doesnt provide an answer to the op question

Comment: by the way it seem that you don't know too much about swift ,,,, if you want i can send you the app running !!! cheers

Comment: LOL, if your passwords aren't encrypted in some form, they are by definition not stored securely.